# FileUpload without transferring files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to provide a way for the user to specify a path to a file on his machine on my intranet web application, and the ASP:FileUpload control provides a nice dialog to do that, however it also transfers the contents of the file over. Since I only need the file path and not the contents, is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** : The code below will return the full file path in IE, but for [security reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Updating_web_applications_for_Firefox_3#File_upload_fields), firefox and chrome only give you the file name. This might be a bit of a problem :)

---

I took the liberty of implementing the solution given by RaYell. Here's the code:

**Default.aspx (markup):**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SO._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitFormWithoutFile() {
            var fileUpload = document.getElementById('<%= this.FileUpload1.ClientID %>');
            var filePath = document.getElementById('<%= this.FilePath.ClientID %>');
            filePath.value = fileUpload.value;
            fileUpload.parentNode.removeChild(fileUpload);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:HiddenField ID="FilePath" runat="server" />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Do it!" OnClientClick="submitFormWithoutFile();" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs (code-behind)**

```
namespace SO
{
    using System;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                // we have our file name but not the file
                this.form1.Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = this.FilePath.Value });
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(this.FileUpload1.PostedFile == null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a FileUpload control. Then before your form is submited you could copy the file path to some hidden input and remove FileUpload control with JavaScript.

I've never tried that but it should work. Don't know the purpose though.

Comment: I think he can copy the value of a file input which holds the path to the file to another (hidden for example) input that will be passed to server.